# Parsing File Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex

I need to parse the first part of a file name as document name with multiple exceptions.

FileName:  :Test FileName Service, LLC - 11-30-12 ASW.pdf"

```
update Test_Base_Form
set [Document Name]=LEFT([Document Name],CHARINDEX('-',[Document Name]) - 1)
where docid={sys docid}
```

Which worked fine, giving me the results of Action Production Service, LLC. I ran into issues later and found that I had some file names like: "Test-FileName Non-Production - 1-12-13.pdf".

To fix that issue I added a space before and after the "-".

```
update Test_Base_Form
set [Document Name]=LEFT([Document Name],CHARINDEX(' - ',[Document Name]) - 1)
where docid={sys docid}
```

New issue what can I do when the file name has a space only after or before the "-", it's throwing off my results by cutting the name short. Is it possible to check for each of these exceptions before returning a value?

Answer (score 0):

```
update Test_Base_Form
set [Document Name] =
    case
        when [Document Name] like '% - %' then
            LEFT([Document Name],CHARINDEX(' - ',[Document Name]) - 1)
        when [Document Name] like '%- %' then
            LEFT([Document Name],CHARINDEX('- ',[Document Name]) - 1)
        when [Document Name] like '% -%' then
            LEFT([Document Name],CHARINDEX(' -',[Document Name]) - 1)
        else
            [Document Name]
    end
where docid={sys docid}
```